# 404.html, ASP.NET MVC root directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have found couple of solutions for error pages in MVC. Most of the solutions are based on Routes and a separate Error controller. But I need a most simple html based error pages, with no preprocessing at all.

Is there a way to serve 404.html, 403.html and 500.html files bypassing the routes file, as static content?

I have placed those three html files in my `~/Views/Shared/` and the following in web.config, the one at application root:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <error redirect="~/500.html" statusCode="500" />
    <error redirect="~/404.html" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/403.html" statusCode="403" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

But it throws error at third line of the above XML locally and from remote it throws 500 internal error with a default IIS theme.

Which directory is considered root for serving static HTML files?

Comment: Have you tried the root directory?

Comment: You mean project's root? Yes that did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CustomErrors mode should be "On" or "RemoteOnly", and the CustomErrors tag should not be closed - as @Preyash Desia stated

```
<customErrors mode="On">
```

Comment: Are you asking or answering?

Comment: Agreed, not the best way to answer. Thanks for your feedback. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off">
    <error redirect="~/500.html" statusCode="500" />
    <error redirect="~/404.html" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/403.html" statusCode="403" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

You have got extra "/" at the end of line 2, its invalid xml; remove it.